# Creating a function to loop over data frame to create distributions of significant correlations in R

Tags: r, function, loops, correlation

I have trouble creating a function that is too complex for my R knowledge and I'd appreciate any help.
I have a data set (DRC_epi) consisting of ~800.000 columns of epigenetic data. I'd like to randomly draw 1000 samples consisting of 500 column names each:

```
set.seed(42)
y <- replicate(1000, {
  names(DRC_epi[, sample(ncol(DRC_epi), 500, replace = TRUE)])
  })
```

I want to use these samples to select samples of a different data frame (DRC_epi_pheno) from which I want to create correlations with the outcome variable of my interest (phenotype_aas). So for the first sub sample it would look like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(correlation)

DRC_cor_sign_1 <- DRC_epi_pheno %>% 
  select(phenotype_aas, any_of(y[,1])) %>%     
  correlation(method = "spearman", p_adjust = "fdr") %>%
  filter(Parameter1 %in% "phenotype_aas") %>%  
  filter(p <= 0.05) %>%                        
  select(Parameter1, Parameter2, p)
```

From this result, I want to store the percentage of significant results in an object:

```
percentage <- data.frame() 
percentage() <- length(DRC_cor_sign_1)/500*100
```

The question I have now is, how can I put it all together and automate it, so that I don't have to run the analyses 1000 times manually?

So that you have an idea of my data, I create here a toy data set that is similar to my real data set:

```
set.seed(42)
DRC_epi <- data.frame("cg1" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg2" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg3" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5), 
                    "cg4" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5), 
                    "cg5" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg6" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg7" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg8" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg9" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5),
                    "cg10" = rnorm(n = 10, mean = 1, sd = 1.5))

DRC_epi_pheno <- cbind(DRC_epi, phenotype_aas = sample(x = 0:40, size = 10, replace = TRUE))
```

Comment: I get error at line `correlation(method = "spearman", p_adjust = "fdr")`. It returns `Error in cat(insight::format_table(formatted_table)) : argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @RonakShah, thanks for the comment. Did you run the first bit (y <- replicate(1000, {
  names(DRC_epi[, sample(ncol(DRC_epi), 500, replace = FALSE)])
  }) as well?

Comment: I didn't get your error, but I edited the part to `replace = TRUE `, as the sample is way smaller than my real sample. Sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Hmm...actually I still get the same error at the same line. `DRC_epi_pheno %>%  select(phenotype_aas, any_of(y[,1])) %>% correlation::correlation(method = "spearman", p_adjust = "fdr")` returns the error `Error in cat(insight::format_table(formatted_table)) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`